# suspend $watching of ng-repeat while updating the list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch, angularjs-digest

I have a page with a MapBox map showing some markers, and a panel showing some info for each marker. To do that, I add the markers in an array called `markers` owned by the controller `ctrl`.

```
map.featureLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) 
    {
        var marker = e.layer;                    
        //add marker to the list
        ctrl.markers.push(marker);
    });
```

Then, in my html panel, I have something like

```
<div ng-repeat="marker in ctrl.getMarkers()">
  {{marker.name}}
</div>
```

It works, but when I set the markers with `map.setGeoJSON(x)`, it fires the event `on('layeradd')` for each marker added. Each one of them automatically fires a `$scope.$digest`. Is there a way to suspend watching the array `markers`, add all the markers, and then resume it?

I tried this solution (from [codewall](https://coderwall.com/p/d_aisq/speeding-up-angularjs-s-digest-loop)), but it doesn't work

```
 $rootScope.$on('suspend', function () 
 {
        watchers = $rootScope.$$watchers;
        $rootScope.$$watchers = [];
      });

 $rootScope.$on('resume', function () 
 {
        if (watchers)
          $rootScope.$$watchers = watchers;
        // discard our copy of the watchers
        watchers = void 0;
});

.....
$rootScope.$broadcast('suspend');
map.setGeoJSON(x);
$rootScope.$broadcast('resume');
```

[UPDATE 1]

as @YOU suggested, I tried to use a temp_array to make modifications. So now `ng-repeat` watches `ctrl.markers`, but I add and remove items to `ctrl.temp_markers`. When I've finished the update, I do `ctrl.markers=ctrl.temp_markers.slice(0)`.
Even in this way, I see that the digest cycle is applied for every item in the array :(

Comment: each scope has each $$watchers I believe. normally don't use $scope variable that use on ng-repeat, but assign to it when you done.

Comment: updated my answer, following your solution. Anyway... it's better, but it's still not what I wished..